# android:How to move a RelativeLayout permanently after animation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation

This is the activity.xml and content_my.xml is a RelativeLayout and menu.xml is LinearLayout. Content layout(RelativeLayout)in the top and menu layout(LinearLayout) under the  I want to move the Relative layout(content layout) left of screen and access the menu layout under it. content layout is in the top of menu layout after animation it menu cannot be accessed. In contentlayout I have add ListView. Please help me how to move the RelativeLayout left permanently after animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.bwd.demo.mybrand.My">

<include layout="@layout/menu" />
<include layout="@layout/content_my" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your content_my.xml you have to assign an ID to your RelativeLayout :

```
android:id="@+id/rl_content"
```

Then you cast the xml in Java code in your Activity so you can use it :

```
RelativeLayout rl_content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_content);
```

Now there are multiple options to animate it.
Since you want to access something below the layout, I would recommend
using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html), then you can do it with one line.

A minimal implementation would look like this :

```
rl_content.animate().translationX(0); // -> animates **TO** 0 on the X axis
```

would move the left border of the layout to the left side of the screen. If you want it further then you need a negative value.

or you can use the translationXBy() method f.e. :

```
rl_content.animate().translationXBy(-50);  // -> animates **BY** -50 on the X axis
//(negative values are to the left)
```

Also interesting :

[TranslateAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) -> not recommended in your case, because it does not really move the layout, only makes it look like its moving, so you would have trouble accessing the menu under the RelativeLayout.

[ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html)